# angular-bootstrap (tabs): data binding works only one-way

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-scope

I prepared a little fiddle and boiled it down to the minimum:

http://jsfiddle.net/lpeterse/NdhjD/4/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.foo = "42";
}
</script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    1: {{foo}}<br />
    2: <input ng-model="foo" />
    <tabs>
        <pane heading="tab">
            3: {{foo}}<br />
            4: <input ng-model="foo" />
        </pane>
    </tabs>    
</div>
```

In the beginning all views reference the model `Ctrl.foo`.

If you change something in input `2:` it properly updates the model and this change gets propagated to all views.

Changing something in input `4:` only affects the views included in the same pane. It behaves like the scope somehow forked. Afterwards changes from `2:` don't get reflected in the tab anymore.

I read the angular docs on directives, scopes and transclusion, but couldn't find an explanation for this undesired behaviour.

I would be grateful for any hints :-)

Comment: JSFiddle is currently down. You should include whatever code is relevant in the question anyhow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is the same as in ng-repeat when you edit a primitive - the `<pane>` directive creates a new scope which inherits from the parent.

Now, given the way Javascript inheritance works the `<pane>` directive has its own copy of the `foo` string primitive, and when you edit it you are only editing it on the pane child scope.

A simple solution would be to put `foo` in an object on your parent Ctrl:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = { foo: 42 };
}
```

Then you can do this in your HTML:

```
<tabs><pane><input ng-model="data.foo"></pane></tabs>
```

Why does it work with an object?  Because when `<pane>` inherits the parent's scope, its reference to `data` will refer to the same object in memory as on the parent Ctrl.  Primitives like strings and numbers are copied in inheritance, and objects simply create a new pointer to the same object.

TL;DR: `<pane>`'s new scope inherits the `foo` string primitive as a new copy of `foo` which when edited won't change on the parent Ctrl. `<pane>`'s new scope **would** inherit an object like `data` as a reference to the same object, and when edited on the `<pane>` scope the same object would be referenced on the parent scope.

Helpful article: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance

Comment: Okay, as you explain it makes kind of sense. I hadn't expected that a new scope literally copies the elements from the scope it is derived from which of course leads to this behaviour for primitives.
Still, very confusing that that new scope is created on first write. Before that the views still reflect directly the original scope.
tl;dr: don't use primitives :-)

Comment: @Lars, primitives are not copied when the child scope is created.  See my answer for a little more clarification on when/how the parent scope primitive values get "copied" to the child scope.

Comment: This sorted it for me!

Answer (score 4):

The `<tabs>` and `<pane>` directives each create a new transcluded child scope (because they both have `transclude: true,`) which prototypically inherits from the parent scope, and an isolate child scope which does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope.  The `<input...>` inside the `<pane>` uses the transcluded child scope.

When the `input` inside the `<pane>` is first rendered, it is populated with the value of `$scope.foo`.
Normal JavaScript prototypal inheritance comes into play here... initially `foo` is **not** defined on the transcluded child scope (prototypal inheritance does not copy primitives), so JavaScript follows the prototype chain and looks at the parent object/$scope, and finds it there.  `42` is put into the textbox.  The transcluded child scope is not affected/changed (yet).

If you edit the first textbox, the second textbox is updated because JavaScript is still using prototypal inheritance to find the value of `$scope.foo`.

If you edit the second textbox, to say `429`, Angular writes the value to `$scope.foo`, but  note that $scope is the transcluded child scope.  Since `foo` is a primitive, it creates a new property on that child scope -- that's how JavaScript works, for better or worse.  This new property will shadow/hide the parent scope property of the same name.  Prototypal inheritance is not in play here.  (The article Andy mentions in his post (which is also [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482)) also explains this in detail, with pictures.)  Since the transcluded child scope now has a `foo` property, it will now use that local property for reading and writing, so it appears "disconnected" from the parent scope.

Using an object (rather than a primitive) solves the problem because prototypal inheritance is then always in play.  The transcluded child scope gets a reference to the object in the parent scope.  Writing to `data.foo` writes to the `data` object on the parent, not the transcluded child scope.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the tabs directive. I think on [line 1044 of ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.1.0.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-0.1.0.js#L1042).

If you change `scope: {}` to `scope: { foo: '='}` it should give you a two-way data binding.

From [Angular Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localModel:'=myAttr' }, then widget scope property localModel will reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in localModel will reflect in parentModel.